# Bootstrap grid not working when file is included

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already made a homepage including the grid system of bootstrap, but now im using mainly includes to keep everything tidy but the grid system doesnt seem to work at all. even if i copy the example code of bootstrap itself.

this is the first code of my content php file. including obviously the row part. These are stacked ontop of eachother not next to eachother.

PS: the .content-wrapper has no styling yet so its not affecting anything and the .content has only top and bottom padding.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="content">
        <h1>The Test Heading</h1>
        <p>
          text
        </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the index.php file i got with the content area

```
 <div class="container">
 <!-- Navigation area -->
 <?php include_once ("php/navigation.php");?>
 <!-- Carousel -->
 <?php include_once ("php/carousel.php");?>
 <!-- Content area -->
 <?php include_once ("php/content.php");?>
 </div> <!-- end of container -->
```

im not sure if it has to do something with including a file and the grid system, but carousel, container etc all working fine so it should find the  css file after being included.

Sidequestion: is a method like this useful? working with includes only? or is it rather non-practical?

Comment: You are missing one <\div> in first file, and maybe you are not including bootstrap files?

Comment: sry thats my bad, first file is part of it, everything is closed correctly (after that thumbnail is another content div which then closes twice,) and as i said i included the bootstrap within the index.php and it is working. If i change the container to .container-fluid, everything changes to container-fluid.

i tried including the bootstrap files within the content.php file, but it also doesnt work.

Comment: So what do u want to do with grid system, bacause you only have one col so it will just go from begining of file to col 6 it will look like it doesnt do anything rly?

Comment: oh jesus, ye ure right. i just had a brainfart. nvm this thx for the hint if u want u can write that i also have to copy the "col.." div in order for it to work.

like that i can mark u as helpful >.<

Comment: Here you go so ppl know u fixed it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what do u want to do with grid system, because you only have one col so it will just go from begining of file to col 6 it will look like it doesnt do anything rly?  You can put lets say    and then your div with  col and it will move it and so on.